# Infinite loop when validating login

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I am working on a program that validates an id and password, and I think I am running into an infinite loop on the validation. When I click the Login button, nothing happens. I'm new to Java and don't yet know what to look for to fix this.

The code is as follows:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    success = false;

    // Sequential search
    int i = 0;

    while (i < validID.length) {
        ;
    }

    {
        if (idField.getText().compareTo(validID[i]) == 0) {
            if (passwordField.getText().compareTo(validPassword[i]) == 0) {
                success = true;
            }
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }

    if (success == true) {
        headerLabel.setText("Login successful");
        idField.setText("");
        passwordField.setText("");
        idField.requestFocus();
    } else {
        headerLabel.setText("Unsuccessful. Try Again");
        idField.setText("");
        passwordField.setText("");
        idField.requestFocus();
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: For a second there, I thought IntelliJ went overzealous with the code formatting.  Turns out that I was wrong.

Comment: Have you tried adding a break point in the first line of your method and stepping through your code? I think you'll see what David is talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i = 0;

while (i < validID.length) {
    ;
}
```

This is clearly an endless loop if `validID.length` is greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

What's the purpose of this block?

```
while (i < validID.length) {
    ;
}
```

If `validID.length` is larger than `i`, which it most likely is, that loop will never terminate.

It seems like you want to remove the extra braces (and semicolon; that thing has to go) to make the block make sense. Here's what that looks like:

```
while (i < validID.length) {
    if (idField.getText().compareTo(validID[i]) == 0)  {
        if (passwordField.getText().compareTo(validPassword[i]) == 0) {
            success = true;
        }
    }
    i = i + 1;
}
```